# How to catch the event of a instant or casting spell?

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to implement a script that catches when my character casts a certain spell like for example a [**Chaos Bolt**](https://www.wowhead.com/spell=196670/chaos-bolt) which has casting time or a **[Shadow Word: Pain](https://classic.wowhead.com/spell=589/shadow-word-pain)** (instant cast). Searching i found the "channeling" events, but i don't quite understand yet.

I'm expecting to trigger a custom message or play an audio when the character casts a certain spell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UNIT_SPELLCAST_SENT](https://wow.gamepedia.com/UNIT_SPELLCAST_SENT): "unit", "target", "castGUID", spellID"

[UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED](https://wow.gamepedia.com/UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED): "target", "castGUID", spellID

Every spellcast has a unique *castGUID*.  It is created when you begin casting with UNIT_SPELLCAST_SENT, and it appears at the end of cast/channel or instantly in the UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED.

So whenever *unit == "[player](https://wow.gamepedia.com/UnitId)"*, just record the *castGUID* and then look for spells completing with that same value.  This is how you know it was not someone else's spell.

Meanwhile, you can lookup the *spellID* corresponding to every spell.  In the example below, I used the two from your post (196670 and 589).

```
local myFrame = CreateFrame("Frame");
local myCurrentCast;
myFrame:RegisterEvent("UNIT_SPELLCAST_SENT");
myFrame:RegisterEvent("UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED");
myFrame:SetScript("OnEvent",
    function(self, event, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
        if (event == "UNIT_SPELLCAST_SENT" and arg1 == "player") then
            print("I am casting something");
            myCurrentCast = arg3;
        elseif (event == "UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED" and arg2 == myCurrentCast) then
            if (arg3 == 196670) then
                print("I just finished casting Chaos Bolt!");
            elseif (arg3 == 589) then
                print("Look at my instant Shadow Word: Pain.  Isn't it cool?");
            end
        end
    end
);
```

This example creates a frame, registers the two events, and then creates an event handler to print out fancy text when you cast the two sample spells.  For a tutorial on event handlers, I recommend [Wowpedia/Handling_events](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Handling_events).

Comment: Thank so much for the explanation, i just have doubts, which argument corresponds to what?
arg1 = unit
arg2 = target
arg3 = castGUID
arg4 = spellID
Is this it ?

And from where are you verifying the **"player"** from?
Is it like **and self == "player") then** ?

Comment: @ImNightShadow it's documented in the wiki linked by Dahk, eg.: https://wow.gamepedia.com/UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED , replicating this here piece by piece is probably a bit too much. The `and "player"` part in the example here I'll assume is incomplete and effectively does nothing in this case.

Comment: Typo corrected.   It was supposed to read arg1 == "player".

@ImNightShadow - You are correct that the args are in that order for the UNIT_SPELLCAST_SENT event.   Note its different for UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED which is why I linked both.